# Renaming .cpp File led to Losing my Code in xCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, rename

I renamed my .cpp file on my mac from "main" to my own name "aac" and when I opened up the project in xCode, it was just blank:

[image]

I want to rename my .cpp file to the project name, but how do I do this without messing this all up?

Comment: Doesn't the IDE have an option for renaming files? If so, first rename the file back and then use the IDE.

Comment: Ah! I just figured out how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh wait. Nevermind. It didn't work for the .cpp file. Hmm. That's odd.

Comment: Now I found out how to do it. I had to rename it in the Project Navigator under the Project File for the cpp file. I thank you for helping me.